# Код на php для загрузки изображений не работает, подскажите в чем проблема

Tags: php, fileupload

```
    $target_dir = "./files/".$_FILES['product_photo']['name'];
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["product_photo"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = 
    strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    // Проверка, является ли файл изображением
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["product_photo"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
    echo "Это изображение - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
    echo "Файл не является изображением";
    $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Проверка, существует ли уже файл
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Извините, файл уже существует";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Разрешены только файлы JPG, JPEG, PNG и GIF";
    $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Проверка, не установлено ли для $uploadOk значение 0 из-за ошибки
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "К сожалению, ваш файл не был загружен";
    // если все в порядке, поробуем загрузить файл
    } else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["product_photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "Файл ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["product_photo"]["name"])). 
    " был загружен";
    } else {
    echo "К сожалению, при загрузке вашего файла произошла ошибка";
     }
    }
```

Comment: Как именно не работает - ты видишь пустой экран? Твой компьютер взрывается? Вместо файла загружается гигабайтный зип-архив?

Comment: Прочитай также [tour] и [ask].